# JHipster Gateway with legacy REST service

Tags: jhipster

I've setup a POC with the following components:

- JHipster registry
- JHipster API gateway
- 2 JHipster microservices

The communication works very well between these components.

Another requirement of my POC is to register an legacy webservice(SOAP or REST not developed with JHipster) in the JHipster gateway.
Is it possible? 
I would want to use the API Gateway as a unique entry point for all the clients(external and internal)to access all the webservices of my company.
Thank you.

Comment: The services are and will be developed with various technologies :  SAP-Rest Odata, Spring boot(without JHipster), Soap or Rest services exposed by software providers (packages not managed by our company).

Comment: How do you want to use these apps is not clear, do you want to expose through gateway or to call them for JHipster microservices ? Do you expect to benefit from rate limiting, circuit-breaking, load-balancing for legacy too? Could you describe the interactions between legacy apps and services ? Are these legacy services going to be called for client code on the gateway? Please edit your question rather than commenting

Answer (score 1):

Two important criteria are service discovery and security.

For service discovery, JHipster offers 2 options: JHipster Registry (Eureka) and HashiCorp Consul. Consul is better suited for legacy apps as it is less invasive because you can use DNS resolution and templates and a sidecar proxy approach.

For security, legacy apps should be able to consume authentication tokens to apply authorizations.

Comment: Is HashiCorp Consul equivalent to a product like WSO2 API Management?

Comment: Not at all, please read their doc and JHipster's too https://www.jhipster.tech/consul/

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I have the feeling that the couple JHipster gateway/Consul is equivalent to WSO2 API Management.